# Identify functions in given package/file

Tags: function, parsing, go

**What im trying to do:**

I am trying to write a program that reads a **.go** file and stores it as, lets say a String. Afterwards I want to somehow identify all Functions in that file and store them separately, e.g. in a slice of functions. The latter is where i am stuck. I tried to match the funcs using regex, but it seems to be very hard to match each individual func that way.

So basically what I am asking for is a way to get **each individual** function in a given file and store it in a container somehow.

Example code

```
func check(e error) {
if e != nil {
    panic(e)
}

func main() {
f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../test.txt")
check(err)
s := string(f)
SearchFunctions(s) }
```

I'm expecting to be able to identify and store the ***main*** and ***check*** function in this file and store them.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [go/parser package](https://godoc.org/go/parser) to parse the source to an AST.  Use the [go/ast package](https://godoc.org/go/ast)  to search for functions.

```
src := `package example

    func myfunction() {
        log.Fatal("blah")
    }
    func aDifferentFunction() {
         panic("blah")
    }`

// Parse the file.
fset := token.NewFileSet()
f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "example.go", src, 0)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var functions []*ast.FuncDecl

// Walk the AST looking for functions.
ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
    if n, ok := n.(*ast.FuncDecl); ok {
        functions = append(functions, n)
    }
    return true
})

for _, n := range functions {
    fmt.Printf("\n---\nfound function %s at %s\n", n.Name.Name, fset.Position(n.Pos()))
    printer.Fprint(os.Stdout, fset, n)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5bDo93BQNSF).